# Sending a value with Event

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

Is there any way to send a parameter , with an event ?

Like this:

```
<CheckBox x:Name="chk1" Content="" Height="16" Width="17" Checked="MultipleSelectMeasurement(1)"/>

....

        private void MultipleSelectMeasurement(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e,int a)
        {
             System.Console.WriteLine("Check Box Nr: "+ a);
        }
```

Sorry I'm a newbie with this things.

Comment: possible duplicate of [C# Event Argument passing](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17256024/c-sharp-event-argument-passing)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Set the [`Tag`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.frameworkelement.tag.aspx), cast the `sender` to `FrameworkElement`, get value from (parsed/cast) `Tag`.

Comment: Can you show me how ?

Answer (score 1):

I can show you an example of that..

```
<Button Tag="passingParameter" Click="Button_Click" />
```

Then from code behind use..

```
private void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
     Button button1 = (Button)sender;
     NavigationService.Navigate(new System.Uri(button1.Tag.ToString()));
}
```

Also see..

- [How do you pass parameters from xaml?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4802278/how-do-you-pass-parameters-from-xaml)